# How to use SYSTEMConfigPerformance on a MPLAB X project

Tags: microcontroller, pic, oscillator, mplabx

I started a new project for a pic 32 (pic32mx470f512l) with MCC.

And now i want to use the function SYSTEMConfigPerformance to optimize the performance of the pic.

It happens that i'm not able to find the library that has it.

The main of my code:

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
#include "xc.h"
/*
                         Main application
 */
int main(void)
{
    // initialize the device
    #define GetSystemClock() 60000000 
    SYSTEM_Initialize();
    SYSTEMConfigPerformance(GetSystemClock());
    while (1)
    {
        // Add your application code
        IO_RD5_Toggle();

    }

    return -1;
}
```

Maybe that function doesn't work with MCC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need [PIC32 Peripheral Library](https://www.microchip.com/SWLibraryWeb/product.aspx?product=PIC32%20Peripheral%20Library)

> Starting with XC32 V1.40, PIC32MX peripheral support libraries are no
>   longer installed as part of the compiler’s installation. These
>   libraries are now installed as a second setup, after the installation
>   of XC32 compiler.